# Multi-cell Li-ion battery charging

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, cell-balancing

I am trying to make a charger circuit for a battery pack consisting of 6 lithium ion batteries (cells) in series. Many battery charger ICs support multi-cell charging but do not provide cell balancing or protection. How should I connect the charger IC, a balancer IC and a protection IC (the last 2 could be in one IC I guess) with the cells?

Also, is there a single IC that handles battery pack charging, balancing, and protection?

Comment: There are multi-cell charger IC's that provide cell balancing. You merely have to use the right search terms.

Comment: Intersil (now Renesas) has a bunch of these.

Comment: I did a lot of searching and the ones I found do not support 6-cell packs (including Renesas). Please give me an example instead of criticizing how I search.

Comment: A Bing search of "liion 6 cell balance ic" brings up several candidates ...so maybe your search is flawed.

Comment: What comes up is a group of battery monitoring/balancing ICs, not chargers with balancing capabilities.

Comment: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/isl94208.pdf looks like it does everything.